# Responsive CSS changes not updating when browser resized

Tags: asp.net, css, mobile, browser

I'm working on an asp.net site and making it responsive, just using @media commands in the stylesheet.

Usually when I work on apache websites, e.g. wordpress as soon as I refresh the page, I can resize the brower to a mobile or tablet size and see the changes on a PC browser. But with this .net site the changes don't show.

They do show however on my actual mobile phone, but I don't want to have to keep previewing changes through my phone.

I've tried using an emulator like mobiletest.me but that doesn't display the changes either. I've tried using Firefox and Chrome, neither work. It seems the website isn't being fooled into thinking my browser is a mobile.

Anyone have an an idea on what this issue could be?

Thanks

UPDATE

Sorry code below:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

#block1 {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: You media query is probably looking for a mobile device, rather than a resolution size alone. Can you show is your media query?

Comment: We can't help if you don't show the code, please add it to your question

Comment: you have bugs, a lot of bugs...

Comment: Code above - just standard stuff

Comment: Yup, as i suspected, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An educated guess says that you are using a specific media query for devices, rather than resolution alone, which is why it's not responding when you resize the window.

Mobile devices: *(what i suspect you have)*

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    /* Styles */
}
```

Based on Resolution: *(what you require)*

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 320px) {
    /* Styles */
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense though? If I implement your code there is no maximum width, so the changes will appear on anything over 320px, e.g. PCs, not just mobiles/tablets.

Comment: Set a max width then. The key part is the *device* part of the query. Remove it.